# Take screensot and save android

Tags: java, android, memory, screenshot, image

I'm a very new android developer with a basic understanding of java. I've undertaken a large project and I've hit a problem I can seem to fix.

Basically my problem has three different parts:

1. I need to take a screenshot of my layout. I can't just use the built in screenshot function, it needs to be done on button press.
2. I then need to crop the picture so that the picture is only of an `ImageView` and the `TextView` that is on top of it. (Unless there is a simpler way to do this?)
3. Finally I need to save the cropped picture to some kind of memory, whether it is the sd card, the device's memory, or to gallery(not preferable).

Any help is much appreciated, thanks a lot

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    tools:context=".Preview" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/bottom_black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="bold"
        android:text="Edit" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:src="@drawable/block" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_fb_sel" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_twit_sel" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/save" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_trash" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="55dip"
        android:layout_height="44dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView7"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_album" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="55dip"
        android:layout_height="44dip"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:maxHeight="44dp"
        android:maxWidth="55dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_new" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView7"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_options" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="55dip"
        android:layout_height="44dip"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_marginRight="-30dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:maxHeight="44dp"
        android:maxWidth="55dp"
        android:minHeight="44dp"
        android:minWidth="55dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_edit" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="297dp"
        android:layout_height="297dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="65dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my xml code

Comment: it way too much commenting. i can't do that anymore. The name entered by the user is a string.

Comment: the name entered by the user is a string. I don't know what you are talking about. String name= input.getText().toString();

Comment: So is the name the variable "file" or "name"?

Comment: i am not sure why the image is not displaying it in gallery. It is stored in sdcard and when i open gallery may be it fetches all images from phone memory and sdcard. But i am sure it gets stored in sdcard. I used samsung galaxy s3 for testing

Comment: @Raghunandan any chance you could test your app on the emulator from eclipse and tell me if it works there?

Comment: i am busy answering a question. posted it here. i will test it on my device and let you know

Comment: post the code now i will give it a try

Comment: @Raghunandan i mean the code you posted in your answer. I essentially just copy pasted it. I just don't see the image in my gallery

Comment: i have tested it and it gets stored in sdcard and it does show in my gallery. you see the snap shot below. has gallery icon also

Comment: is that in the emulator though? I thought that was on an actual device?

Comment: i tested on device. you need to create a sd card on emulator and mount the same

Comment: How large should the sd cad be? what size is the average image?

Comment: i am not sure about it. if you still have doubts ask a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

My layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/rl"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:src="@drawable/afor" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

My Activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RelativeLayout rl; 
final int PIC_CROP = 1;
ImageView iv;
 File file;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
     Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
     iv= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
     b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
     {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          save();
     }
     });
}

   public void save()
   {
       AlertDialog.Builder editalert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
       editalert.setTitle("Please Enter the name with which you want to Save");
       final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
       input.setLayoutParams(lp);
       editalert.setView(input);
       editalert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
               rl.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
               String name= input.getText().toString();
               Bitmap bitmap =rl.getDrawingCache();
               String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
               File myDir = new File(root + "/MyDraw");    
               myDir.mkdirs();
               file = new File (myDir, name+".png");
               if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();         
               try 
               {
                   if(!file.exists())
               {
                   file.createNewFile();
               }
                   FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                   bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
                   ostream.close();
                   Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                   performCrop(uri);                          
               } 
               catch (Exception e) 
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       });
       editalert.show(); 
   }


   private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {
    try {

   Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
   // indicate image type and Uri
   cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
   // set crop properties
   cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
   // indicate aspect of desired crop
   cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
   cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
   // indicate output X and Y
   cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
   cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);
   // retrieve data on return
   cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
   // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
   startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
 }
 // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
 catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
  // display an error message
  String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
  toast.show();
  }
 }




 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

 if (requestCode == PIC_CROP) {
  if (data != null) {
      // get the returned data
      Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
      // get the cropped bitmap
      Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
      FileOutputStream ostream;
    try {
        ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        selectedBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
         ostream.close(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

      iv.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap);
  }
  }
  }
```

snap shots

My Layout snap shot

[image]

On button click prompting the user to enter a name to save

[image]

Image cropped and saved opened in gallery

[image]

Note: I have saved the cropped image in sdcard. The snap shots size varies.
This worked for me on my device. I have posted the same. If anyone has a better idea pls edit the above post.

Manifestfile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.cropimagefromsdcard"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.cropimagefromsdcard.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, but I'm getting an error. "The field ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT is deprecated" Is there a proper way to do this? Will this still work?

Comment: @James have you used the above code coz it works for me and i have posted the snapshot. check this for a similar link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976714/setcontentview-and-layout-android. The code above works. if not you are doing somethign wrong

Comment: One thing that might be causing my problem is my manifest. I'm not entirely sure where or ho to implement the code into my manifest to allow my app to write to external storage. Any chance you could show more of the manifest so I can see where in the manifest it goes?

Comment: @James this more than what i would normally post. check the edited answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the link btw. I've looked at it and I think I know where my problem is. I have a relative layout already created through xml. And I have a lot of stuff set up in it, and then I turn around and added a new layout through my .java file. Will your code work without adding that layout? and thanks for posting the manifest

Comment: i don't know what you are trying to do. yes it should work. set this rl.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true) enabled for your layout for which you wish to take screen shot. in the above its relative layout

Comment: My app crashes whenever I try to open that activity and my logcat is telling me my imageView cannot be cast to Button. In past when I've had this error the solution was to clean my project, but now it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Posted my xml. Feel free to ask if you need anything else

Comment: @James no problem in xml code. try clean and build or create a new xml and paste the code there. set the content to your activity.

Comment: What do yo mean by set the content to my activity?

Comment: just a try copy the contents to a different xml. say test.xml and set content as setContentView(R.layout.test);

Comment: Was the setContentView(R.layout.test); included in your code? I'm not sure where it's supposed to be and might that be the problem? and i'll try that

Comment: forget it. clean build your project.

Comment: i am not sure what more i can do to help you. i posted a working code with snap shot. that's the max i can do .

Comment: I'm an idiot, your code worked fine, but I actually tried to cast an imageView as a button. Sorry for all the trouble and thanks a lot

Comment: Yup will do, also I just tested and thankfully got no errors, but the image didn't show up in gallery? I'd assumed it would be shown in the gallery app, but it's not. Is it saved elsewhere?

Comment: in my case it was stored in sdcard and i opened the same in gallery

Comment: How do I open it in gallery in the emulator?

Comment: i am not sure about your device. i have a galaxy s3 and i browsed the image and used the gallery app to view the same.image stored under sdcard under MyDraw folder

Comment: Ok, well I currently only have access to an emulator, so that may be the problem. Thanks for your answer though it helped a lot.

Comment: @James you can also upvote my answer to show your appreciation by clicking the up arrow once

Comment: Is there a way to make it so that the name entered by the user could be bound to a string?

Comment: would you please tell me how to attach the name entered by the user to a string?

Comment: The picture, unlike yours, is not displaying in the gallery

Answer (score 0):

Hey You Can just use the below Code to capture screen shoot in android and save it in ur SDCard and then you can use it later

```
// image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + ACCUWX.IMAGE_APPEND;   

// create bitmap screen capture
Bitmap bitmap;
View v1 = mCurrentUrlMask.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

OutputStream fout = null;
imageFile = new File(mPath);

try {
    fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then, when you need to access use something like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mPath));
```

Comment: My app will end up saving multiple pictures and I need to be able to access each of them individually from another activity. Is there a way to change the name of the file for each picture that is saved?

Comment: You can save the image wit current `Time` and `Date`.Is the above code working in your scenario?

Comment: @James on button click prompt a pop for the user to enter a name and then save. Do want that as a solution? i can post the same for the save part.

Comment: @Raghunandan that would work I'm pretty sure, I'm just wondering if there was an easier way? Like naming the file after an int value that += 1 every time a file is saved?

Comment: @Ayush It's part of the answer I need so thank you for that, I still need the other two parts though

Comment: @James i am not aware of an alternative solution but if you need the solution of prompting a popup to allow the use to enter the name i can post the solution.

Comment: @James take  look at this link http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/07/how-to-crop-image-from-camera-and.html

Comment: @James you can try my answer posted.