# Uploading android file by name from sd card

Tags: android, sd-card, social-media

In a previous question ([Take screensot and save android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489086/take-screensot-and-save-android)) I found out how to save a file to the sd card of an android device and it works properly. Now I need to know how to find the file programatically by name, and then upload the file to facebook or twitter. Currently my biggest issue is just to find the file.

Answer (score 3):

To get path of file from gallery

```
String filepath; // filepath contains path of the file

public void  getImage()
{
    // To open up a gallery browser
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),1);
    // To handle when an image is selected from the browser, add the following to your Activity
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            // currImageURI is the global variable I'm using to hold the content:// URI of the image
            Uri currImageURI = data.getData();

            File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI));

            if (file.exists())
            {
                filepath=file.getAbsolutePath();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("File Not Found");
            }
        }
    }
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri)
{
    // can post image
    String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery( contentUri,
        proj, // Which columns to return
        null, // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
        null, // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
        null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

To get image from sdcard

```
    File file = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyDraw");
    if(file.exists())
    {
        File myfile = new File(file.getAbsoluteFile()+File.separator+"name.png");
        String path = myfile.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

To upload file to a server. I am not aware of how to upload file to facebook or twitter.
In general to upload file to server

```
    public void upload(String filepath)
    {
      try
      {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("youe url");
        File file = new File(filepath);
        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
        mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile);
        httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```

Comment: Do I need to know the whole path and everything? Or do I just need to know what the user named the picture?

Comment: @James you require the path of the file to upload the image to the server. The path will give you location of the file form which you upload same kind off stuff you do to upload pic from your desktop.

Comment: @James the code for which is posted in the answer above. have you tried the above??

Comment: I am trying it now, but I see what may be a problem. It checks if there is a file present and takes the file, but there will likely be 2 or more pictures there

Comment: @James it does not matter as you are fetching the path using the file name.

Comment: here is a noob question: please specify the classes we need to import!

Comment: @rptwsthi what IDE do you use. if i include all the imports then the post will be huge. its unnecessary and you should know what to import. that's the basic. If you use eclipse you right click -->source--> organize imports and fix imports or ctr+shift+o

Comment: Thanks and I completely agree with that huge part, also guy sitting next to me just told me this. But couldn't resolve these two classes:  `MultipartEntity`, `ContentBody`.

Comment: look for apache commons httpclient4.2.jar for older versions of android. for new versions http is included in the framework.

Comment: `import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;`
`import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ContentBody` this is what i used from the httpclient4.2.jar.

Answer (score 0):

first you need know th path of image and then use the facebook sdk to upload the picture in the profile

https://developers.facebook.com/android/

in the sdk exist one example for upload a image

Comment: @james do you need to get the image from gallery? or you need ot get image from sdcard in case you know the file name

Comment: @James to let the user choose from gallery you can use the first part of the code. it will give you the path of the image choosen. if you know the name of the file in sdcard you can get the path using the second part. To upload file to server in general you can use http post request