# Saving View bitmap with getDrawingCache gives a black image

Tags: android, image, caching, view

Everything I tried with `setDrawingCacheEnabled` and `getDrawingCache` was not working. The system was making an image but it just looked black.

Other people on SO seemed to be having a similar problem but the answers seemed either too complicated or irrelevant to my situation. Here are some of the ones I looked at:

- [Save view like bitmap, I only get black screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489000/save-view-like-bitmap-i-only-get-black-screen)
- [Screenshot shows black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610404/screenshot-shows-black)
- [getDrawingCache always returns the same Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610699/getdrawingcache-always-returns-the-same-bitmap)
- [Convert view to bitmap on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536066/convert-view-to-bitmap-on-android)
- [bitmap is not saving properly only black image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721851/bitmap-is-not-saving-properly-only-black-image)
- [Custom view converting to bitmap returning black image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535675/custom-view-converting-to-bitmap-returning-black-image)

And here is my code:

```
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
    try {
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir() + "/image.jpg");
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);
        stream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

I'm sharing my answer below in case anyone else makes the same mistake I did.

Comment: Working fine for me just follow this link code [convert view to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48935539/7589424)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My problem was that my `view` was a `TextView`. The text on the `TextView` was black (naturally) and in the app the background looked white. However, I later recalled reading that a view's background is by default transparent so that whatever color is below shows through.

So I added `android:background="@color/white"` to the layout xml for the view and it worked. When I had been viewing the image before I had been looking at black text over a black background.

See the answer by @BraisGabin for an alternate way that does not require overdrawing the UI.

Comment: Be carefull with this answer. More info: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/performance/debug-gpu-overdraw/index.html

Comment: Useless backgrounds are bad for performance. If you need a background in your UI there is no problem to use it. Just think that if you draw 3 backgrounds at the same pixel the only necessary one was the last one.

Answer (score 11):

I just found a good option:

```
final boolean cachePreviousState = view.isDrawingCacheEnabled();
final int backgroundPreviousColor = view.getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor();
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(0xfffafafa);
final Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
view.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(backgroundPreviousColor);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(cachePreviousState);
```

Where `0xfffafafa` is the desired background color.

Comment: I haven't worked on this for a while, but I starred my question to come back to it in the future and test this out. For now +1.

Answer (score 3):

Used below code to get `bitmap` image for view it work fine.

```
 public Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
         DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
         v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(dm.widthPixels, 
         View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
         View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(dm.heightPixels, 
         View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
         v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
         Bitmap returnedBitmap = 
         Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(),
         v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
         Canvas c = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
         v.draw(c);

        return returnedBitmap;
}
```