# How to display file from sd card on android emulator

Tags: android, emulation, sd-card

I asked this ([Take screensot and save android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489086/take-screensot-and-save-android)) question awhile ago and got an answer that I accepted. My problem now is that unlike the answer, my file isn't displaying in the emulator. Does anyone have any idea how to make it display there?

Comment: You will need to post some code relative to your question. Not all of it, but at least the part where you are setting the `ImageView`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? All of the code I used to save the picture was posted in the answer to my first question that I linked?

Comment: Perhaps people are asking for your code used to *display* the picture.  Though you might first want to test it's validity by adb pulling it and opening it on your development machine, or using a file manager or gallery app to view it on the device.

Comment: I mean, post the `java` code that gets your `bitmap` from the sd card, and sets it to an `imageview`. It should be 5-10 lines tops. That way anyone trying to help you doesn't have to look through that disaster of a post and go through hundreds to thousands of lines of code to find out exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: I see what you mean now, but the problem is that the picture is created by the app and by the user, not pulled from the internet or the SD card