# Get the path of a file saved to the android SD card

Tags: java, android, path, sd-card

In the question [Take screensot and save android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489086/take-screensot-and-save-android) someone informed of how to save an image created in my app to the SD card. Now I'm trying to upload the picture, but first I need to find how to get the path. The entire code that I used is in the last question, I need to know how to get the path to the image that I saved. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check these lines:

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + "/MyDraw");    
myDir.mkdirs();
file = new File (myDir, name+".png");
```

`file` is the File object that points to the location where the Bitmap is saved.

Answer (score 0):

When `onActivityResult()` gets called back in your application, the intent contains the uri of where the file was stored. Pull it out of there and save it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need the name that the user entered to save the filename with. You can save the filename the user inputted by saving to a pref (or they just entered it, then you should still have it). Once you have the filename, you can simply get the file by:

```
String fileName = //get the file name
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/MyDraw");
f = new File(f, fileName);
```

---

If you don't know the filename, you can loop through the file directory:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirector(), "/MyDraw");
for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
    //Do something with this file
}
```